# Logo not showing in header _Layout.cshtml asp net core

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, asp.net-core

There is a project on Asp Net Core 6. The application has 2 areas.
[route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX3vP.png)
When I log in with default user images display correctly. but when the address bar changes to localhost:44316/Admin/Category - the image disappears
[javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTWEq.png) [_Layout.cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkwgc.png)
But when route is localhost:44316/ - images show correctly
wwwroot hierarchy:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtL0u.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @Oleg Pogorelov, where is your `Admin/Category`  action/pagemodel location? Does it in area or just in Views/Pages foloder? Pls share more details.

Comment: Also, could you pls share the js code instead of picture? Where do you put this js code?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the ../images in _Layout.cshtml to ~/images

Comment: Does not give any result(